# Plnkr.co editor script does not recognize jQuery

Tags: jquery, plunker

I use plnkr.co to test a jQuery animation, but the editor gives a "$ is not defined" error on the lines that starts with $... What is wrong? As normal files on my computer this works fine...

jQuery is loaded (together with other bootstrap, as set up by Plunker):

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.0-rc2" data-semver="3.0.0-rc2" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.0.0-rc2" data-semver="3.0.0-rc2" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

And then script.js has:

```
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-button').click(function (el) {
    console.log("Klikk!");
    $('#search-form').toggle(duration);
    $('#add-form').toggle(duration);
    el.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/azhaoBjlGYX1xGV5JVLS?p=preview
See script.js and the lines with the yellow warning signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JSLint/JSHint issue. It's an implicit global so you have to instruct the linter that it's ok.

Add `/* global $ */` above your code and the warnings will [disappear](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjqg9NPcYtXt7W5lSLbZ?p=preview).

Comment: Hmm, how come I cannot find this global-thingy on f.ex. this http://plnkr.co/edit/Cq5rPf4MnKGeAGYyepzL See first js-file, where the angular app is set up (or in any other file or settings)? What did I miss?